# Creating similar file structure as JSON object with hierarchy?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have various folders and files in a bucket in Amazon S3.

Now we are trying to build a similar hierarchy structure as json format to render it in UI.

I understand we can find the folder or file difference with "/"

Could someone help me with suggestions or feedback on how to create a hierachy structure with parent and child relationship so that the structure will be rendered in UI?

Do we have an amazon API to retrieve as hierarchy as JSON or any other format?

Comment: S3 currently only supports an XML API, which has the ability to do some of the pseudo-folder detection using `prefix` and `delimiter` parameters.  The problem with your idea is that a nested JSON structure will need to be rendered on  server and will grow very large and eventually not scale well. The S3 list objects API requests are also more expensive than get objects requests.  In one environment, I programmatically maintain pre-rendered JSON "manifests" of "folder" contents, static object lists maintained by S3 events and Lambda when objects change. What is your application for this?

Comment: My sample application it to list the file structure similar to S3 like filezilla to provide add, delete access of files and folders via java